# Change geometry while iterating over geodataframe

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I want to compare geometries between geodataframe. If any of the two geometries overlap then I need to remove the overlapped geometry from one of the polygon.

For e.g. I have these 3 geometries within geodataframe

```
1. POLYGON((2 1,4 1,4 4,2 4,2 1))
2. POLYGON((3 3,5 3,5 5,3 5,3 3))
3. POLYGON((1 0,3 0,3 2,1 2,1 0))
```

There is an overlap between `(1,2)` and `(1,3)`. So I want to change the geometries in such a way that the overlap is removed.

I have written this code but doesn't seem to work

```
for i in range(0, len(geo_dataframe) - 1):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(geo_dataframe)):
        p1 = geo_dataframe.iloc[i][0]
        p2 = geo_dataframe.iloc[j][0]
        if p1.overlaps(p2):
            if p1.area > p2.area:
                geo_dataframe.iloc[j][0] = p2.difference(p1)
            else:
                geo_dataframe.iloc[i][0] = p1.difference(p2)
```

and in the console I am getting `SettingWithCopyWarning`: warning. Not sure if this is stopping from replacing the geometry since it is a warning and not error. I tried to look into it but couldn't understand it.
The function `difference` is giving me correct result but when I print `geo_dataframe.geometry` it prints the original geometry.

Comment: Found one solution geo_dataframe.at[j, 'geom'] = p2.difference(p1) but not sure if there is any better way to do that.